# Excel: Como fazer um série temporal usando tabela e gráfico dinâmicos com acúmulo de valores na linha?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Gostaria de fazer um gráfico de série temporal em que indicasse os valores acumulados ao longo do tempo. Portanto, não seria uma linha zig-zag, seria uma linha denotando uma evolução, conforme os valores são acumulados.

Para ilustrar, anexo duas imagens. A primeira eu consegui fazer com os recursos tabela dinâmica e gráfico dinâmico. Ele mostra os valores reais e a linha em zig-zag. A segunda (que é a que eu gostaria) fiz "na mão", apenas para ilustrar aqui, não consegui fazer automaticamente. Como seria possível?

Os dados são os que seguem:

```
Ano     Qtt 
1945    1 
1961    1 
1964    1 
1966    2 
1970    1 
1971    1 
1972    1 
1973    1 
1980    1 
1981    3 
1982    1 
1983    1 
1984    2 
1986    3 
1987    4 
1988    1 
1989    4 
1990    6 
1991    11 
1992    5 
1993    13 
1994    6 
1995    11 
1996    14 
1997    23 
1998    7 
1999    12 
2000    12 
2001    20 
2002    19 
2003    58 
2004    30 
2005    69 
2006    223 
2007    201 
2008    113 
2009    71 
Ignorado    28 
Total Geral 981
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer o gráfico da segunda imagem, a partir dos dados abaixo. Note que os valores vão acumulando. Isso que estou chamando de evolução.

Ano Qtt
1945 1
1961 1
1964 1
1966 2
1970 1
1971 1
1972 1
1973 1
1980 1
1981 3
1982 1
1983 1
1984 2
1986 3
1987 4
1988 1
1989 4
1990 6
1991 11
1992 5
1993 13
1994 6
1995 11
1996 14
1997 23
1998 7
1999 12
2000 12
2001 20
2002 19
2003 58
2004 30
2005 69
2006 223
2007 201
2008 113
2009 71
Ignorado 28
Total Geral 981

Comment: Favor editar a pergunta com estas informações e tente colocar o valor na tabela deste site: [https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), para facilitar a sua pergunta a ser respondida.

Comment: daniel, não consegui inserir os dados através deste site, desculpe, sou muito iniciante por aqui. Coloquei como imagem, espero que possa ter esclarecido melhor. Grato e abraços!

Comment: Você deseja fazer um gráfico, mas sem utilizar uma coluna extra? Porque se utilizar uma coluna extra é possível adicionando uma fórmula simples em outra coluna, digamos que os valores estão na coluna `B`, então em outra coluna adicione: `=SOMA($B$2:$B2)` e use o auto preenchimento até a última linha. Assim os valores acumulados podem ser vistos.

Comment: Valeu, Daniel, se houver uma solução que não adicione coluna extra, seria melhor, pois são vários gráficos que farei. Mas, de toda a forma, a solução que você apresentou já ajuda! Grato!

Answer (score 1):

### Solução

Você pode utilizar o gráfico do tipo Cascata para visualizar os valores acumulados.

### Passo a Passo

**1. Selecione os dados:**

Selecione os dados a serem vistos no gráfico de acumulados.

[image: Selecionar células]

**2. Inserir gráfico:**

Insira o gráfico em `Inserir > Gráficos Recomendados > Todos os Gráficos` e escolha o Cascata.

[image: Cascata]

### Resultado

O gráfico ilustra o valor cumulativo e quanto acumulou em cada ano acima da barra.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: A ideia é exatamente essa e desse jeito fica muito bom. Vou tentar instalar (se é que dá) esse tipo de gráfico no meu excel (2013) já que ele não apresenta essa função. Super valeu!

Comment: Utilizei o Excel 2016 para realizar isto.